Laravel 11 Route not found 404 jQuery
I'm using Laravel 11 and jQuery
I have this error :

Erreur 404: Not Found

{
"message": "The route %7B%7B%20route('columns.all')%20%7D%7D could not be found.",
"exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",
Here is the code of my road
Route::post('columns/all', [ColumnController::class, 'getAllColumns'])->name('columns.all');

Here is my js code (jQuery) :
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    alert("ici");
    var routeUrl = "{{ route('columns.all') }}";
    // Fonction Ajax pour charger des données
    function loadData() 
    {
            $.ajax({
            url: routeUrl,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json', // Indique que la réponse attendue est en JSON
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' // Indique qu'il s'agit d'une requête AJAX
            },
            data: {
                _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') // Ajout du jeton CSRF pour sécuriser la requête
            },
            success: function (response) 
            {
                console.log(response); // Vérification de la réponse
            
                let select = $('#column_description'); // Supposez que vous avez un <select> avec cet ID
            
                // Vider les options existantes
                select.empty();
            
                // Ajouter une option vide
                select.append('<option value="">Select a column</option>');
            
                // Itérer sur les données et créer une option pour chaque colonne
                response.forEach(function(column) {
                    select.append(`<option value="${column.id}">${column.identifiant}</option>`);
                });
            },
            error: function (error) 
            {
                // Afficher un message d'erreur détaillé dans une alerte
                let errorMessage = `Erreur ${error.status}: ${error.statusText}\n\n${error.responseText}`;
                alert(errorMessage);

                // Affiche également l'erreur complète dans la console pour plus de détails
                console.error('Erreur complète:', error);
            }
        });
    }

    // Appeler loadData() lorsque la page est chargée
    loadData();
});

the alert launches correctly.
this code is in a separate file, but when I put it in my index.php file, the route is found without problem.
Thank you for the help.


Pass the Route URL as a JavaScript Variable in the Blade File:

    <script>
        var routeUrl = "{{ route('columns.all') }}";
    </script>


Add this routeUrl variable in your jquery ajax function:

     url: routeUrl

It should be work now.

Woaw, works great, thank you so much !!!! but, would you be so kind as to explain to me why we have to do this please? The important thing for me is to understand in order to improve. Thanks again and have a good start to the week.

Because, Blade syntax only works in .blade.php files, so we pass route URLs to JavaScript variables in the Blade view to make them accessible in external JavaScript files.
